# Sort of copy constructor of derived class with base class parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

So I want to have a constructor for my derived class to which I give an instance of my base class such that my base class is initialized with the input parameter and my derived class follows the default constructor.
I came up with this (MWE):

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
Derived(){a = 0; b=3;};
Derived(Base * base): Base(*base),Derived(){};
int a;
int b;
}
```

But this gives me the error `error: constructor delegation follows mem-initializer for 'Base'`

So how should I do this? I know one way that works but I'm asking if there is a better way such that I don't have the same code in the default constructor and the other constructor.

So I know that this works:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
Derived(){a = 0; b=3;};
Derived(Base * base): Base(*base){a = 0; b=3;};
int a;
int b;
}
```

Comment: Your class is called `Derived`, but it doesn't look like you have any inheritance... Did you mean to define it as `class Derived: public Base {`?

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry I'll edit the question

Comment: Copy constructor's parameter should be `const Base&`

Comment: `Derived` has only `private` members and maybe definition of `Base` is relevant. If only `struct Base {};` is sufficient to reproduce the error you can add that

Comment: Oke maybe the name copy constructor is misleading. I want a sort of copy constructor. With your suggestion @YaroslavStetsyk I'll still get the same problem I think. (haven't tried though)

Comment: How the `Base` looks like? It doesn't sound right to implement copy constructor from `Base`, I would just go for: `Derived(int x, int y): Base(x, y) {}` if the `Base` has some example 2 fields x and y.

Comment: Yes, "copy constructor" is misleading. A copy constructor takes an argument of its own type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, `Derived(...):Derived(){}`; calls default `Base` constructor. So adding additional call to constructor of `Base` confuses compiler - how should it know what you want?

You can write it as follows if you wish to avoid code duplication:

```
     class Derived : public Base 
     {
        public:
        Derived()=default;
        Derived(Base * base): Base(*base){};
        int a = 0;
        int b = 3;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that a constructor defines, is how members and bases are initialized. *All* non-delegating constructors define initializers for *all* members and bases, either explicitly or implicitly. Your zero-arg `Derived` constructor, for instance, default-constructs `Base` and `a` and `b`; in a more idiomatically written version `Derived() : a(0), b(3) {}` it would default-construct `Base` and initialize `a` and `b` with 0 and 3 respectively.

So something like `Derived(...) : Base(foo), Derived(bar)` is trying to have it both ways. It's trying to use some of the other constructor's initializers, while replacing others. But that's not what delegating constructors were designed to do. A delegating constructor *uses* and *adds to* the activity of another constructor; it doesn't *modify* it.

The general idiom is for constructors to delegate to more explicit constructors. In this case, it sounds like the defaulting of `a` and `b` to 0 and 3 would ordinarily be done by delegating to a constructor which sets them directly. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish by accepting a pointer to a base class. That's weird and probably not good.

Finally, I should say that while delegated-to constructors aren't open to modification by delegating constructors, default member initializers *are* open to replacement by explicit initializers. If you just initialize `int a=0, b=3` in the class definition, each (non-delegating) constructor can decide whether to let those defaults stand or whether to replace some of them.